# Google StaticMap image not shown in Firefox

Tags: html, google-maps, cross-browser, image

I've build this image [1](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=38.0413,14.0225&size=640x460&zoom=16&maptype=hybrid&markers=color%3ared|38.0413,14.0225&sensor=false&format=jpg-baseline) and put in an src attribute of an img tag.
The image is shown if I access it directly from the browser but when I put it in a page in this way the image is not shown

```
<img src="$STATIC_MAP_URL" />
```

If I see the the image with Firebug it is shown, it's strange because Firebug show the img tag gray, as if it is hidden, but it's not.

Other browser haven't this problem and show the image as it is supposed to be.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd *guess* that you are failing to encode the ampersands and Firefox is being stricter about something. Does the page [validate](http://validator.w3.org)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I passed the URL through htmlentities() PHP function and now the ampersands are encoded as &amp; but the problem is still here.

Comment: Now I've tried on Windows+Firefox (4/Nightly) and it works...so the problem is GNU/Linux+Firefox (3.6/4.0). Still not understand why. Maybe an extension?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to encoding the ampersands, make sure you encode the "|" to "%7C" too.  I was struggling to get static maps working correctly on Blackberry Devices due to the pipes.